# How to count the values in ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have two columns as shown below. Group values is 0,1,2,3,4 and scores is from 0 to 80. I want to count how many 0s (1s, 2s, 3s, 4s) are present for scores between 0 and 10; 10 and 20; 20 and 30 etc.

I am thinking to use Excel pivot table. But I am stuck - how could I achieve this?

```
Group scores
1   8.56163
2   34.3649
2   12.2291
0   8.75357
2   8.75967
2   5.87806
0   9.33751
2   32.0303
0   43.5567
2   11.1044
2   24.9266
1   18.9314
```

-------- result should look like below --------

```
scores  group   count

0-10    0        2
0-10    1        1
0-10    2        2
0-10    3        0
0-10    4        0

10-20   0        0
10-20   1        1
10-20   2        2
...
```

------ PS I have solved this problem using [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab). But it would be nice to see someone do it in Excel.

---------------- thanks for all the anwers. I really appreciate it. I have accepted the 1st answer.

Comment: updated what's the result should be like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for my previous answer. You *can* do binning with PivotTable.

- select your whole two columns (A1:B13), insert PivotTable
- under rows, put your "Group"
- under columns, put your "scores"
- under values, put your "Group"
- click that last one ("Group" within the values quadrant) and change it to count, not sum

intermediate result:

[image]

Now in the resulting pivot table, right click on a colum and select "Group and show detail". You can configure your bins there.

Result:
[image]

Comment: quick question, when I set groups (eg starting at 0, ending at 90, by 10). this will give me groups (0,10), (10, 20), etc. My question is how does the borders are included/counted in each group?

Comment: Afaik its exclusive of the upper limit, so [0;10[,[10;20[,[20;30[

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

[image: SO38876372 first example]

This uses Grouping (by decade) for the Row labels.

To Group, right-click on one of the entries under Row Labels and Group..., then select enter Starting at:, Ending at: and By: to suit:

[image: SO38876372 second example]

Comment: how did you set 'grouping'?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a pivot table, but another option is to use `COUNTIFS`, e.g.:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,"="&$F2,$B$2:$B$13,">="&D2,$B$2:$B$13,"<="&E2)
```

In practice:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just use simple countif formulas:

Type out first criteria into cells. D1 = 0, E1 = 1, F1 = 2 etc.

Now you can just say `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$13,D1)` and just drag that out.

The other column would require countifs.

Lets say D3 is blank E3 = ">10", F3 = ">20", etc.

Now D4 = "<=10", E4 = "<=20", F4 = "<=30", etc.

Now you can use `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$13,D4)` for your first criteria and `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$13,E4,$B$2:$B$13,E3)` for the next criteria and just drag that out.

Hope this helps, good luck!